# TNS entries in Linux

Tags: database, linux, oracle, unix

I have to update TNS entries in a Linux server. I am trying to search tnsname.ora file but unable to.
"locate tnsname.ora" is not giving me any result."find $ORACLE_HOME -name tnsnames.ora" is also not giving any result. I went to the path /usr/lib and then did ls , but I do not have any "oracle" dir under it, Result of "/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/NETWORK/ADMIN"
-bash: /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/NETWORK/ADMIN: No such file or directory

And where can I update the TNS entries?

Comment: Are you sure you need to update the entries on the server, not a client machine? If the server doesn't have any applications that act as clients then you may never have created a `tnsnames.ora`. If it does exist then as @igr says it will [either be under `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` (lower-case), `$TNS_ADMIN`] (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/network.112/e10835/tnsnames.htm#i433681), or possibly `/etc/` or `/var/opt/oracle` in some versions/operating systems.

Comment: have you tried to widen your search....go to the root folder then: find. -name tnsnames.ora

Answer (score 0):

Try with netca or netmgr executables (if available). Be sure to know TNS_ADMIN environment variable - if set.
network/admin is lowercase on *nix (if my memory is good)

Comment: hi, i searched in another server i found it but only in this server I am unable to locate tns file, sqlplus is not available on the server ( Oracle DB) hope it is not required?

Answer (score 0):

Just create tnsnames.ora under this one location and paste all entries to this one file.